# Having problem with joining condition while joining 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am having following structure of the tables:

Table A:

```
SSN     a_id     b_id.  Date              Sent
123      1        2      12/11/2020        1
```

Table B:

```
SSN     a_id     b_id   Date.             OPen
123      1        2    13/11/2020          1
123.     1        2.   14/11/2020          1
```

Table C:

```
SSN     a_id     b_id   Date.             Clicks
123      1        2    13/11/2020           1
123      1        2    14/11/2020           1
123      1        2    14/11/2020           1
123      1        2    14/11/2020           1
123      1        2    15/11/2020           1
```

I am using:

```
select *
from Table A
left join Table B on A.SSN = B.SSN and A.a_id = B.a_id and A.b_id = B.b_id
left join Table C on A.SSN = C.SSN and A.a_id = C.a_id and A.b_id = C.b_id
```

I want the following output:

```
Table Ans
SSN     a_id     b_id   Date.             Sent       Open      Clicks
123      1        2    12/11/2020           1          0         0
123      1        2    12/11/2020           0          1         1
123      1        2    12/11/2020           0          1         1
123      1        2    12/11/2020           0          0         1
123      1        2    12/11/2020           0          0         1
123      1        2    12/11/2020           0          0         1
```

The order of 1 and 0 in each column doesn't matter. But the count of it should be same as there in Original tables. How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you thought about using union all instead of join?

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy Union All with give me dates from the joined tables. I want the date to be same as that from base table i.e table A

Comment: @thorsten kettner

Comment: your example doesnt show that. so you mean if there isn't a date in table A, but is in B or C, you don't want them into your result set?

Comment: @LongBeard_Boldy 
We will have date in table A always. And in result set also, we need date from table A

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, this is the result set you actually wanted to get or something similar to it.

```
with a as (select * from (values (123,1,2,'2020-11-12',1)) a(ssn,a_id,b_id,"date",sent))
    ,b as(
          select * from (values (123,1,2,'2020-11-13',1)
                               ,(123,1,2,'2020-11-14',1)
                        ) a(ssn,a_id,b_id,"date",open))
    ,c as
         (select * from (values (123,1,2,'2020-11-13',1)
                               ,(123,1,2,'2020-11-14',1)
                               ,(123,1,2,'2020-11-14',1)
                               ,(123,1,2,'2020-11-14',1)
                               ,(123,1,2,'2020-11-15',1)
                         ) a(ssn,a_id,b_id,"date",clicks)
         )
 select  ssn, a_id, b_id,"date", sum(sent) as sent, sum(open) as open, sum(clicks) as clicks
  from (
       select ssn, a_id, b_id,"date",sent,0 as open,0 as clicks,"date" as hidendate  from a
        union all
       select a.ssn,a.a_id,a.b_id,a."date",0 as sent,open,0 as clicks,b."date" as hidendate from a,b where a.a_id = b.a_id and a.b_id = b.b_id  
        union all
       select a.ssn,a.a_id,a.b_id,a."date",0 as sent,0 as open,clicks,c."date" as hidendate from a,c where a.a_id = c.a_id and a.b_id = c.b_id  
        ) q1 
 group by ssn,a_id,b_id,"date",hidendate
 order by date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `full join`:

```
select *
from a full join
     b
     using (ssn, a_id, b_id, date) full join
     c
     using (ssn, a_id, b_id, date);
```

This returns the `0`s as `NULL`s.

If you want `0`s, use:

```
select ssn, a_id, b_id, date,
       coalesce(a.sent, 0) as sent,
       coalesce(b.open, 0) as open,
       coalesce(c.click, 0) as click
from a full join
     b
     using (ssn, a_id, b_id, date) full join
     c
     using (ssn, a_id, b_id, date);
```